# Copying from the PGN viewer

Tags: feature-request

I often want to transfer a position from the PGN player to, say, the LiChess engine. I really, *really* want to avoid clicking on "Edit", copy the raw data, and undo the edit. So, what is the correct way to "un-code" the PGN player? (Tagged feature-request; I'm fairly sure the feature exist and I'm just too stupid.

Comment: What you describe is the way I do it too ... An alternative would be (for now) to switch to the mobile view (with the 'Mobile' link in the footer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the right side of the bar above the PGN player diagram is a down arrow/triangle. It is a menu with options to:

- Copy Game
- Copy Position
- Copy Start Position

It is a floating box, so it doesn't always appear right below the arrow. After selecting an option, another box appears with either the PGN of the game, a FEN of the current position without the castling, en passant, or half-move counts, or the full given FEN for the starting position.

Comment: Accepted, although it definitely doesn't work for me, either due to my quite hardcore script settings, or due to my small monitor resolution. The latter also explains why I never spotted it before :-)

Comment: Because my eyesight isn't that great, I need big pixels, and set my screen to 1280x720px. The pop-up appears so far below the top of the screen that its second item is only just visible at the bottom, and the third is not displayed. The code that displays the pop-up needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate option is to view the page source with a right-click anywhere on the page. Then you can find the PGN with Ctrl+F and copy-paste it from there. Whether it's less hassle or not, I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Now that you say it... :-) It is doable, but definitely more hassle, especially with more than one diagram, as modern HTML looks like as the pigs have eaten lunch on it. Glorfindel's "Mobile" suggestion definitely is elegant and working, but "Copy FEN"/"Copy PGN" buttons still would be nice.